# Comparing Simple Sounds - What is the Closest Frequency

Tags: c#, audio, fft

I have a rather interesting problem to solve.

I want to take a very simple sound (one note played on the piano) and try to process it in such a way that I can print out which note is most likely being played.

From some googling and searching I have come across the fast fourier transform but am not entirely sure how I would use this to analyze data from a wav file.

Another thought I had was that a note should be more or less the same each time it is played. If that is the case could a percentage match on two wav files turned into byte arrays be of any use?

Thoughts and ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FFT is a much better option than comparing two WAVs. The FFT will produce a frequency spectrum, and since the piano produces a relatively pure tone, you will observe very distinct spikes when you plot it. The position of each spike denotes one of the constituent frequencies of the waveform, with the largest spike representing the note.

Comment: Yes, this way you determine the fundamental frequency of each of the two sounds. Those two frequencies may differ slightly because of imperfections in the piano, mic, etc, so you can't compare them directly. Instead, construct the pitches for all possible piano keys ([here's how](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament#Twelve-tone_equal_temperament)) and snap your two frequencies to the nearest piano key frequencies. If they snap to the same frequency, then the same piano key has been played.

Comment: To construct the possible piano pitches you need to know how the piano has been tuned - you need to know it's reference pitch. It's explained in the above link. In practice your app won't know this so you should assume it's 440Hz.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Please let me see if I now understand correctly:  I can transform my signal into the frequency domain (I have done this with accord.net).  From the frequecy domain I can plot a graph with power on the Y axis and frequency on the X axis.  The biggest spike is the frequency of the note.  So I can read the frequency of the note off the axis and check which note on the piano it is closest to.

Answer (score 0):

You should be analyzing the frequency of the note being played. Im a bit rusty but FFT i think should do this as it breaks down the waveform into frequency spectrum.

You do not want to be comparing the wav file with an already stored one, as the period amplitude etc could be different. A 'percentage match' would produce erroneous results.

Once you have the frequency of the waveform,you can then devise the note that is being played.

Answer (score 0):

I would start reading up on Digital Signal Processing (DSP) and spectral analysis. Sounds like you're trying to find the **fundamental frequency** of your piano note.

To do any meaningful work with a WAV or other file format, you'll need to extract and interpret the audio samples. If not wanting to do so by hand, I'd suggest looking into a myriad of existing DSP libraries. I'm not sure what good c# libraries exist.

The Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) will essentially convert your power over the time domain to the frequency domain, essentially adding a z-axis to your audio.